# wxPython: TreeCtrl: How can I get a tree item by name?

Tags: python, tree, wxpython

I am using wxPython and got a tree with some items.
Now I need a function which give me the tree item object by name.

For example:
item = self.GetItemByName("MyStories")

I can not find such function in the documentation.

Does anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I don't think nodes contain names, only labels, so are you trying to get an item by that?

Comment: can you give a sample code of exactly what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to find the first tree item with a specific label:

```
def get_item_by_label(self, tree, search_text, root_item):
    item, cookie = tree.GetFirstChild(root_item)

    while item.IsOk():
        text = tree.GetItemText(item)
        if text.lower() == search_text.lower():
            return item
        if tree.ItemHasChildren(item):
            match = self.get_item_by_label(tree, search_text, item)
            if match.IsOk():
                return match
        item, cookie = tree.GetNextChild(root_item, cookie)

    return wx.TreeItemId()

result = get_item_by_label(tree, 'MyStories', tree.GetRootItem())
if result.IsOk():
    print('We have a match!')
```

But depending on what you're displaying in the tree, there's probably an easier way to handle it.  The TreeCtrl already provides the tools to create references both ways between tree items and other objects as you fill the tree, and dict lookups are much faster and cleaner looking than what I just typed.

Comment: Yup, adding calling tree.AppendItem() returns a wx.TreeItemId - much easier to track these.

Answer (score 4):

While robots.jpg answer will work but I find a much better solution is to track the ids in a dict like the following (hinted at by @robots.jpg & @Steven Sproat)

```
self.tree_item_ids = {}
root = self.tree.GetRootItem()
for obj in objs_to_add:
    tree_id = self.tree.AppendItem(root,obj.name)
    self.tree_item_ids[obj.name] = tree_id
```

and then later when you need to lookup the item for an object you can just grab the tree_id

```
tree_id = self.tree_item_ids[obj.name]
data = self.tree.GetPyData(tree_id)
```

Comment: tree_id = self.tree_item_ids[obj.name], this tree_id can be directly passed in as the parent object when using AppendItem. data = self.tree.GetPyData(tree_id) fails for me.

Comment: Using `wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl` and `AppendItem` returns an object reference (e.g. `<wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl.GenericTreeItem object at 0x7f11f1dba550>`). So it isn't a `wx.TreeItemId` but this method still works well.

Answer (score 0):

You may also override TreeCtrl and change **tree_ctrl_instance** with **self**

```
def GetItemByName(self, search_text, tree_ctrl_instance):
        retval = None
        root_list = [tree_ctrl_instance.GetRootItem()]
        for root_child in root_list:
            item, cookie = tree_ctrl_instance.GetFirstChild(root_child)
            while item.IsOk():
                if tree_ctrl_instance.GetItemText(item) == search_text:
                    retval = item
                    break
                if tree_ctrl_instance.ItemHasChildren(item):
                    root_list.append(item)
                item, cookie = tree_ctrl_instance.GetNextChild(root_child, cookie)
        return retval
```